# How to make vuejs navbar link active on click without route

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, vue-router

I have a vue bootstrap navbar. All of the nav items have a route except one. The one that doesn't (Contact) launches a modal on click. When an item is selected I want the item to be white.

I do this and it works for items that have a corresponding route:

```
:active='$route.name ==""'
```

**Navbar**

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <router-link class="nav-link" :to="{
                      path: '/',
                      hash: 'home',
                    }" :active='$route.name =="home"'>Home</router-link>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <router-link to="/About" :active='$route.name =="about"' class="nav-link">About</router-link>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" v-b-modal.modal-contact>Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How do I get the Contact item to be active on click?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you and solved it like this.

First, you define a method that will use the `name` property of `this.$route`

```js
export default {
  name: 'App',
  methods: {
    getActiveNavLink(name) {
      //This is for the navbar classes, you can modify them as
      //as you need. (This will be assigned every-time we call this
      //function).
      let classString = "nav-item nav-link "
    
      //We compare the given name with the route current name.
      if (this.$route.name === name) {
        //If it is true, we append to the class string the "active" value
        classString += "active"
      }
      //Return the class string.
      return classString;
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your navbar you do something like this

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">The navegation bar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <router-link 
          :to="{ name: 'home'}"
          :class="getActiveNavLink('home')" >
          Home
        </router-link>
        <router-link
          :to="{ name: 'secondRoute'}"
          :class="getActiveNavLink('secondRoute')"><!--class="nav-item nav-link">-->
          To the second route!
        </router-link> 
        <router-link :to=...>
          ...
        </router-link> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

That way, everytime you call the `getActiveNavLink` you pass the name of the route to compare, and if the name of the route is the same as your `$route.name` you will get an active navbar element!
Also, **dont worry about the router-link classes being overwritten**, they are not, the classes that we add, **are appended**, not overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

its works for me for add class attributte and methods calling

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You could use `router.push()`. When you open the modal, push to that path, when you leave the modal, push to the previous path.

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html